# Reading file with visual c++ form behaves differently than reading in C program

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I'm build a graphical program using visual c++ form.  I'm trying to read a file to a string. The contents of the file is simple html code.

Now, if i create a blank project and create a .c file with this code:

```
FILE *f;
int tamanho;
char *asd;

f=fopen("mail.txt","r");
if(f==NULL)
    erro("Erro abrir file");

fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
tamanho=ftell(f);
rewind(f);
asd=(char *)malloc(tamanho+1);
fread(asd,1,tamanho,f);
```

It copies the whole to the string.

However if I create a windows form application and write the same code it only copies a few lines of my file.

Comment: If you run this program and debug it: what value has the variable tamanho?

Comment: You are allocating "tamanho+1" bytes and then reading "tamanho" bytes into a freshly allocated array.  So...what is in `asd[tamanho]`?  Besides that, what happens if you make it a .cpp file and compile as C++ instead of giving it the .c extension?  As Lucian asks--is the actual value of tamanho in both versions given the same input file, or does it change?

Answer (score 3):

fread() does not guarantee to read everything you ask for.

You need to check the return value to see how much was actually read.
You may need to do this in a loop until you have read everything you want.

```
size_t  read = 0;
while(read != tamanho)
{
    size_t amount = fread(asd + read,1,tamanho - read,f);

    if (amount == 0)
    {    // You may want to check for read errors here
    }

    read += amount;
}
```

Comment: by your code it remains in a infinite cycle. The first iteration it read almost 99% of the file, howerver if i debug and check the contents of the string there only a few lines not even close to 99% of the file.

Comment: Did you check what the error was? feof() and ferror()! If the amount read is 0 then you need to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Missing a while loop? That way u make sure u reach end of file properly

Comment: I assure you that it reaches to whole file, i've even tried using fgets in loop and it reads the whole file. however if i'm reading from file and adding to the string when i reach the end the string only shows a few lines, and there aren't any zeros. I've noticed that visual c++ forms uses c++ compiler instead of a c one. Can that afect the function?

Comment: @user1091446: No it does not read the whole file. fread() may be returning quickly because the disk was busy. This has nothing to do with C Vs C++ just the incorrect usage of fread(). As sys_debug said you need a loop. PS. +1

Comment: Maybe you are reading in more than you can have? Am not sure about this in C but in java, even a string have a max length to consume. So maybe you reached that? somehow I doubt my suggestion is a problem, because if so, it would throw an exception